# div only fit to content and not height

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a design for my homepage, where i have a top with banner and menu, a bottom and a contentarea which is made of three divs that is next to each other. 
I want different stuff in the left one or only use this as a spacer. 
The right column will have some banners in it for non-profit commercials. 
The middle column will have lots of content and this content can be very long or short and i want this content to only be in this column and not float to the sides and therefore i need the design to be somewhat dynamic on heights. What is really the problem is that my container wont move with that extended content in the middle...

Edit:
I have updated the example so it more clearly shows whats i want.
I want all content in the middle region and some other stuff to the left and right and this stuff in the middle can get very long therefore i want that the middle column shall decide on how long the container has to be - if that is possible? If i make the container move, then the left and right column will move with it.

I'm sorry, my english is very limited.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html
{
    height:100%;
}

body
{
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}

.container
{
    height:90%;
    background-color:blue;
}

.left
{
    width:150px;
    height:90%;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid #242F24;
    margin:auto 5px 5px 5px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; 
    background-color:yellow;

}
.right
{
    width:200px;
    height:90%;
    float:right;
    border: 2px solid #242F24;
    margin: auto 5px 5px 5px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; 
    background-color:grey;

}
.middle
{
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
    float: none;
    margin:auto 5px 5px 5px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="left">Left<br>Lorem Ipsum.....</div>
<div class="right">Right<br>Lorem Ipsum.....</div>
<div class="middle">Middle<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an actual height instead of a min-height.
height can be controlled using overflow.
min-height allows the container to grow to the size of the content.

Comment: I've tried that, but if i change the min-height at the body, the containerbackground will stop in the middle of the screen and it will not completely solve my problem ;(

Comment: Try using min-height to provide a minimum height and also using height to control the height. But I don't quite understand how you want it to look exactly. Are you trying to fix the middle container or the left and right columns?

Comment: I have now updated. I don't think you can use both min-height and height at the same time. I guess that height overrule min-height :(

Comment: I thought you might want the left and right columns to always be at least 90% of the height of the page but, as I said, it's difficult without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve!?

Comment: Made a new update. Text couldn't fit in here. It is also hard do describe in a language i don't use very often, but from many other answers i have seen in here you guys seem pretty talented!